# Whatsapp interactive message with twilio

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I can create a whatsapp interactive message with twilio, like a quick buttons?

How can I send this, if I have my whatsapp number and I already use the twilio whatsapp service?

This is the facebook documentation about this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates/interactive-message-templates/?locale=es_LA

Comment: You need to have written some code and share for more help.

Comment: I have just updated my answer, Twilio does now support this. Check the links in my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

The [Twilio API for WhatsApp now supports interactive message templates](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-whatsapp-quick-reply-buttons-for-more-engaging-customer-experiences). Check out [the documentation for using buttons in WhatsApp templates here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).

---

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently you cannot send interactive messages using the Twilio API for WhatsApp. That may change in the future though. If you have set up your WhatsApp number and you were in touch with an account executive, I recommend speaking with them.

Comment: any update on this, Phil?

Comment: The only update I have was the latest edit to the post. Twilio supports interactive messages in WhatsApp through templates. Check out the links in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. As May, 2023 seems like Twilio does not support interactive list messages.

Comment: I recommend that you check out the [docs of the Content API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content-api) which is currently in private beta and request to join the beta :)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I see they have the Interactive lists message in this version. 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/content-api/twilio-list-picker

Comment: Do I need to first create a template using the contents API and then would be able to send interactive messages in a User-Initiated Conversation too? Can't I create the message and directly send it?

Comment: Correct, you need to create a template via the content editor or content api and use this one then.