# How to use Whatsapp template call to actions with variables

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

**EDIT**:
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812450/whatsapp-interactive-message-with-twilio?rq=2), what I want may not be possible.
[This](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content) looks like a promising solution, but as of June 2023, it seems to be in preview.

---

I am implementing a simple notification service for my web app using Twilio Whatsapp Templates. My template has already been approved and is ready to use.
I want to be able to send Twilio call to action but with variables. The Twilio console's UI allows to specify Phone or website calls to actions, but it asks for a hard-coded value. My app is sending a new order notification message, so the values for the website and the phone are not always the same and depend on the order being placed. How can I send templated messages but with a programmatic call to action?

Thins I have checked:

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates#maincontent (general tutorial on how to create templates, does not mention dynamic call to actions)
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/twilio-call-to-action (Seems to be a different product, looks outdated, links to broken pages)
- https://player.vimeo.com/video/587969112?title=0&autoplay=0&muted=0 (Mentions the use of the Twilio studio for something similar, but I would rather not use additional tools).

It seems quite pointless to be able to send call to action in messages but only allow hard-coded ones.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you in advance.

P.S: I am using the Node.js API which does not mention any additional parameters other than to, from and body to send the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered your own question correctly. The [Content API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/overview) is the right service you want to focus on.

Therefore, I would encourage you to request access by filling out this [form](https://pages.twilio.com/messaging-content-api-request-access-1?_ga=2.136649520.1078969667.1687200261-1435018048.1686651066&_gl=1*1xtbl6z*_ga*MTQzNTAxODA0OC4xNjg2NjUxMDY2*_ga_RRP8K4M4F3*MTY4NzI0MzMyMS4xNS4xLjE2ODcyNDM4NjMuMC4wLjA.) or contact your AE/SE (if you have one).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation mate. I will do that